# What's the difference between AMD's APP SDK and (AMD) ATI's Stream Technology?

Tags: sdk, opencl, ati, amd-gpu

I'm working on a project that will use an AMD GPU for processing data.  I noticed AMD has two different SDKs available on their website for using the GPU: [ATI Stream Technology](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/STREAM-TECHNOLOGY/Pages/stream-technology.aspx) and 
[OpenCL™ and the AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/opencl-and-the-amd-app-sdk.aspx). It looks like both support OpenCL but I haven't found anything on the site explicitly pointing out why one would use one over the other.  What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMD APP SDK is here: http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx

The website should also answer your question about the difference between Stream and APP:

> AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing (APP) SDK (formerly ATI Stream)

It used to be called AMD Stream SDK, they probably renamed it after adding support for non-Firestream hardware (namely OpenCL)

Answer (score 1):

stream is the higher level amd-specific project (hardware and software) that includes opencl as the current software implementation.  stream originally used the "brook" language, but [switched to opencl in 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_FireStream#Software_Development_Kit).  since then opencl became more popular (because it is a cross-platform standard that has been particularly well supported by apple) and these days amd doesn't seem to mention stream much.  you can see this in a link like http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/opencl/pages/opencl.aspx where opencl is a "child" of stream (or the menu on the left of that page, where the higher level group is stream; other children are related to hardware).

in short, you want opencl.  and despite the confusing  mess that is amd's site, their opencl implementation is pretty solid.

hmmm.  re-reading your question you seem to say there are two separate sdks.  do you actually drill down to two different packages?  my understanding is that opencl *is* the stream sdk.  if you have found two different sdks (that are both current) can you link to them?

Comment: I haven't drilled down yet; I stopped when I saw the two different SDKs. The more I read, the less I knew.  Before I grabbed these I wanted to see if someone had some insight into them.  Unfortunately, AMD's site didn't help differentiate them.